# How to get last element and to know id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list:

```
<ul id="thumbnails" class="thumbnails"> 
<li class="span12"> <li class="span12"> 
<li id="li2" class="span2"> 
<li id="li3" class="span2"> 
<li id="li4" class="span2"> 
<li id="li5" class="span2">
<li id="li6" class="span2"> 
</ul>
```

I need get ID for last li, i try:

```
num=$('li.span2').last().id;
alert(num);
```

But alert show 'undefined'
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m=$('li.span2').last().id;
```

Correct:

```
 m=$('li.span2').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
num=$('li.span2').last().prop('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.thumbnails').filter('li:last').prop('id')
```

or

```
$('.span2').filter(':last').prop('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var num = $('.thumbnails li:last-child').attr('id');
alert(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `attr` like

```
num = $('li.span2').last().attr('id');
```

Or you can also try with `prop` like

```
num = $('li.span2').last().prop('id');
```

You can also try with `:last` ([**THIS**](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)) like

```
num = $('li.span2:last').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num=$('li.span2').last().attr('id');
alert(num);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHbZt/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumbnails li:last-child').attr('id');
```

or you can use this also

```
$('li.span2').last().attr('id');
```

In your code you didn't add attr and you know id is an attribute and it is compulsory dear.